# Installing Haskell Platform overrides gcc location in system PATH

Tags: haskell, path, mingw, environment-variables

I am running the latest version of MinGW GCC 4.7.2, and it was working fine with `-std=c++11` before I installed Haskell using Haskell Platform. Please take a look at this:

[image]

For some reason, the GCC went back to 4.5.2, after installing Haskell, I re-installed it, with version 4.7.2, but its still showing 4.5.2.

Comment: run `g++ -v` from the same prompt. Also why are you posting a *screenshot of console window*?

Comment: Could it be that you are now running an older g++? What is the output of `g++ --version`?

Comment: I believe you forgot to censor the folder name in the first line

Comment: @MM. actually, both commands show version.

Comment: The problem is in your path. Fix your PATH variable or invoke the compiler from the path where it is installed.

Comment: @ForEveR: True, it shows. but `-v` shows _`Display the programs invoked by the compiler`_ according to `--help`. And the better option is `--version`

Comment: @MM. It's completely irrelevant. both will show the version, and that was obviously what was needed. And neither is *better*, they are different. If any was better, it'd arguably be `-v` for being shorter to type.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz : The first one helped more `g++ -v`, because the path was changed.

Comment: Gcc 4.5.2 does not accept `-std=c++11` but you can use `-std=c++0x`. You should change the title to your real problem: Haskell overwriting your PATH environment with another gcc version

Comment: not very relevant, but you are missing a semi-colon

Comment: This question is not "too localized". It is an example of a very common problem originating in Windows installers adding unrelated programs to PATH. Perhaps a good duplicate to link to would do it justice.

Comment: @rubenvb Voted to reopen, but from the looks of it, it won't make any difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Haskell adds its own GCC to your system PATH. You can check this is true by running

```
where gcc
```

which will show two commands, the Haskell one first, followed by your MinGW GCC.

The solution is to change your PATH to point to the GCC you want (but make sure Haskell still uses its GCC, I doubt it'll agree with GCC 4.7 if it came with GCC 4.5).

The easiest is to have some script ou can run to set up your compilation environment, so you don't have to worry about system PATHs.

If you don't care much about that exact GCC version you had installed, you can get my builds ([32-bit](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win32/Personal%20Builds/rubenvb/) and [64-bit](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win64/Personal%20Builds/rubenvb/)), which come with a `.cmd` file you can doubleclick and it will give you a build environment much like the MSVS commandline shortcut, but for GCC. All it really does is add the compilers to PATH.